# Where are the save files stored?

Tags: steam, windows, shoot-many-robots

Well, pretty much everything is in the title.  Since the game doesn't use Steam Cloud, where can I find back the save files (containing my character's level, etc) ?

The `smrconfig` file located in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Demiurge Studios\Shoot Many Robots\SOMEWEIRDINTEGER\` contains the player's configuration, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.  There's also a `slot()` file in the same folder, but the content isn't human readable.

Note that I've got the PC version, and bought it [from Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/96400/).

Comment: This depends on where you purchased the game from.  Did you buy it through GamersGate?   Somewhere else?

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't know there were other buying methods.  I bought it in Steam.  I'll edit the question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few tests, it seems that the `slot()` file mentionned hereabove contains the character's data (level, equipment, unlocks, etc.)

So if you play on two different computers, you just have to copy/paste this file at the right location: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Demiurge Studios\Shoot Many Robots\SOMEWEIRDINTEGER\`

Answer (score 0):

Run [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and set a process filter to the game's executable. Now you can watch every file the game touches.

Comment: Not really the answer I was looking for, but thanks for the advice ;)